# Putting Numlua on LUA_PATH

Tags: lua, require, scientific-computing

I'm trying to put [numlua](http://numlua.luaforge.net/) on my LUA_PATH so that I can use it from anywhere.  It currently lives in /usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/numlua.  I can successfully require it (numlua) from inside of /usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/numlua . Currently, I have the default LUA_PATH:

```
require "numlua"...

no file './numlua.lua'
no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/numlua.lua'
no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/numlua/init.lua'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/numlua.lua'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/numlua/init.lua'
no file '/usr/share/lua/5.1/numlua.lua'
no file '/usr/share/lua/5.1/numlua/init.lua'
no file './numlua.so'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/numlua.so'
no file '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua/5.1/numlua.so'
no file '/usr/lib/lua/5.1/numlua.so'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
```

However, when I try require "numlua.numlua" from somewhere else, say ~/,:

```
error loading module 'numlua.numlua' from file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/numlua/numlua.so':
    /usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/numlua/numlua.so: undefined symbol: luaopen_numlua_numlua
```

(Needless to say, require "numlua" doesn't work).  I've tried to change my LUA_PATH as well, but whenever the directory/files are on my LUA_PATH I always end up with undefined symbol error.  What's the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NumLua is a C module DLL. The `LUA_PATH` is for *Lua* files. You know, files that end in ".lua".

The search path for C modules is `LUA_CPATH`.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Is there anywhere I can read more about the LUA_CPATH? I've only found small excepts on the mailing list, etc